# Writing and reading to/from a file (using ArrayList) in java

Tags: java, list, file-io, arraylist

So basically, I have had these a few superclasses, with a  of their few sublcasses forming up a small program. As for the file handling, since I was using "Arrays", I used writeobject and readobject method. But now, I have changed all my arrays to "ArrayLists", but when it comes to file handling, it does not work as before, obviously.

there are 2 specific parts that I get error, first is:

```
for(i=0;i<100;i++)
{
customerOOS.writeObject(Customer[i]);//since we no longer have (Customer[]) array, and instead Custarray of arraylist
}
```

.
.
.

Second part:

```
for (i=0;i<100;i++)
{
Customer[i] = (Customer)customerOIS.readObject();//same problem again
}
```

So, what should I replace these parts with, so then it works. Or should I use a completely different way to do file handling of the ArrayLists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `ArrayList` is an implementation of `List` (which is backed by a dynamic array) which is a container of `Objects`.

This container has very specific and well document methods which allow you to manage the list of elements.

In order to retrieve an element from the list, you need to use [`List#get(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29)

```
for(i=0;i<Customer.size();i++)
{
    customerOOS.writeObject(Customer.get(i));
}
for (i = Customer.size(); i < 100; i++) {
    customerOOS.writeObject(null);
}
```

To add a new element, you need to use [`List#add(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28E%29)

```
for (i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    Customer.add((Customer)customerOIS.readObject());
}
```

I would take some time to study the API documentation and have a read through the [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html) trail, as these are very basic concepts

Comment: Thank you! Again my question, for the second loop ( which is adding an element) where do we use the "i" that is declared in the statement, inside the loop?

Comment: You don't need to.  `ArrayList` is a dynamic array, that means that it can grow and shrink of it's own accord (dynamically).  Take some time to read through the [API Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and the [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html) trail, in particular [The List Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html)

Comment: I assume there is something wrong with the get(i) part, that I get this error while executing it.

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
 at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
 at FileHandling.main(FileHandling.java:39)

Comment: @SBOY The problem is, there's nothing in the list.  I've also updated the code to bracket for possible overflow and to bracket the expected number of input objects accordingly

Comment: Now, Compilation Error :'(
cannot find symbol method get(int)

Comment: YUP! that seemed to be working. Thanks a lot mate. You are actually a very good programmer, why the nickname?! haha all the best with everything :)

Comment: @SBOY Because sanity has no place in software development ;)